# Does TDengine database support schemaless?

Tags: database, tdengine, schemaless

Does TDengine support schemaless way of importing data? If so what interface does TDengine provide for users to use schemaless(e.g. through Restful API or other tools)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDengine supports schemsless insert.You can use schemaless through different TDengine connector(like jdbc,c#,c,node,python,go and so on).you can. reference[python's line protocol](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/tree/develop/src/connector/python#insert-with-line-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

TDengine Schemaless writing protocol is compatible with InfluxDB's Line Protocol, OpenTSDB's telnet and JSON format protocols.

TDengine C/C++ Connector provides Schemaless API. From TDengine v2.3 and later versions, users can also use taosAdaptor to writing data via Schemaless through RESTful interface.

Schemaless Protocol and API is [here](https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/insert#data-writing-via-schemale).

Comment: A mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer on Stack Overflow. Please at least summarize what's behind the link.